# Report Scheduling

Tags: sdk, scheduling, cognos

I have written a SDK using java to integrate with Cognos.

This is working fine when normally working with the cognos functionality.
But when I login directly to cognos using my custom namespace, and schedule a report, I am getting an exception (se exception section)

When I googled about this exception, I came to know that my SDK code should generate TrustedCredentials in order to run scheudling. I alread have that code in my JDBCVisa class. But still I am getting the same exception.

Please see the exception and JDBCVisa class code (generateTrustedCredentials specifically):

> EXCEPTION
>   ================================================================================= CM-CAM-4005 Unable to authenticate. Check your security directory
>   server connection and confirm the credentials entered at
>   login.errorcamAuthUnrecoverableCAM-AAA-0194 Authentication to the namespace
>   'xxx' failed.CAM-AAA-0180 The 3rd party provider returned a
>   user recoverable exception.1The provided credentials
>   are invalid.Unable to authenticate a user. Please contact
>   your security
>   administrator.
>
> ## SOAP-ENC:arrayType="cm:baseClass[0]">

```
public ITrustedCredential generateTrustedCredential(
    IBiBusHeader theAuthRequest) throws UserRecoverableException,
    SystemRecoverableException, UnrecoverableException
{
    CreateLog.LogMsg("generateTrustedCredential: Called  ");
    boolean isValidCredentials = true;
    String[] theUsername = null;
    String[] thePassword = null;

    // 1 - Look for credentials coming from SDK request
    theUsername = theAuthRequest.getCredentialValue("username");
    thePassword = theAuthRequest.getCredentialValue("password");

    if (theUsername == null && thePassword == null)
    {
        // 2 - Look for credentials in formfield
        theUsername = theAuthRequest.getFormFieldValue("CAMUsername");
        thePassword = theAuthRequest.getFormFieldValue("CAMPassword");
    }

    if (theUsername != null && theUsername.length == 1
        && theUsername[0].equals(username) && thePassword.length == 1)
    {
        isValidCredentials = this.validateConnection(theUsername[0], thePassword[0]);
    }
    else
    {
        isValidCredentials = this.validateConnection(this.username, this.password);
    }

    if (!isValidCredentials)
    {
        CreateLog.LogMsg("generateTrustedCredential: Invalid credos  ");
        UserRecoverableException e = new UserRecoverableException(
            "Please type your credentials for authentication.",
            "The provided credentials are invalid.");

        e.addDisplayObject(new ReadOnlyDisplayObject("User ID:",
            "CAMUsername", this.username));
            e.addDisplayObject(new TextNoEchoDisplayObject("Password:",
            "CAMPassword"));

        throw e;
    }

    TrustedCredential tc = new TrustedCredential();
    //tc.addCredentialValue("username", username);
    //tc.addCredentialValue("password", password);
    CreateLog.LogMsg("generateTrustedCredential: Successful  ");
    return tc;
}
```

Comment: What line does is the exception thrown at? I guess you have already ensured that you are using valid credentials (i.e. inspect them in your code at runtime and ensure they are what you expect).

Comment: If they were supposed to be the same user and password what I passed at the time og log into the cognos, then YES, I am getting those in generatedTrustedCredential function. Not sure which line throws the error as I am getting the exception at the time when schedule is being run by Cognos and I am getting nothing in log file.

Comment: Is it just me, or are you just instantiating a new, empty TrustedCredential object and trying to use that as the Trusted Credentials in your source above?  The username and password lines are commented out.

Comment: No No.. the code to add username and password is uncommented in the actual code line. One thing I would like to ask is, which user this is supposed to be. Should this be the "Application user". In my scenario this is an application user who has rights in cognos to schedule report. Anything else I need to care about?

Comment: I got the problem and solution too. Problem was code to Generate the Trusted credential was fine but code to Use those credental at the time of Logon was not appropriate. When I made the correction, scheduling starts working. thanks all for your help.

Comment: Could you detail what your solution was and put it in as an answer?